# Redesign the primary key of MySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, sql

We've a requirement to record some official receipt that get renewed every year from an external source (think some banking use case). So we have the table with a primary key as receipt number and other fields like `issue_date`, amount among other things.

Until now our application logic would update the previous receipt. But now we want the version no. column be added defaulted with 0 and subsequent transactions with same receipt number be given an incremented version.

For **example**, receipt_no 1 would be transacted as

> receipt_no -> 1 , version_no -> 0 and next same receipt:
>
> receipt_no -> 1 , version_no -> 1 .

Thus my question is how would I design the table correctly? Do I use a composite key for version number? Will this logic be easy to code in Java JDBC code for data access? Please let me know your inputs.

Comment: For receipt_no 1 (as in your example), are you planning on having multiple records representing each version or when the license is updated, you are overlaying all information and marking the records as version++?

Comment: Just use a surrogate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement an auto-incremented primary key on the table (this is just generally a good idea).

Create a unique index on `receipt_no, version_no`.

Add a `before insert` trigger to determine the new `version_no` when you do an insert.

This assumes that you are not regularly manually changing either of the two fields.